# Generating Binary File in Javascript using Blobs and appending to it in a loop

Tags: javascript, arraybuffer, blobs

I'm following a file specification to generate a binary file in javascript using blobs and arraybuffers. Everything was going well and I had the following blob:

```
var bb = new Blob([fileSig, version, numBlocks], {type: 'example/binary'});
```

The variables `fileSig`, `version`, and `numBlocks` are array buffers with the correct data in them. Now I've come to a point where I have a `for` loop that generates data which also needs to go into this blob.

I first thought I'd create an array of ArrayBuffers that gets populated as the `for` loop continued and then add it to the blob like:

```
var bb = new Blob([fileSig, version, numBlocks, arrayOfArrayBuffers], {type: 'example/binary'});
```

But the blob doesn't take it. Then I thought I'd run a loop on `arrayOfArrayBuffers` and append to the `bb` Blob, but Blobs don't allow appending.

Is there a way to append to an arrayBuffer, or Blob in this way? I need to use both `Uint8Array`, and `Uint16Array`s.

Edit: a `DataView` seems to be what I need to use. I will keep a record of the offset, and then set the new data at that offset. I'll try it and post my findings.

Comment: What about `[fileSig, version, numBlocks].concat(arrayOfArrayBuffers)`?

Comment: Ah of course :) . Yes that would work. I just created an array eg arrayOfArrayBuffers. Pushed all new array buffers into it. and then finally did var bb = new Blob(arrayOfArrayBuffers, {type:'example/binary'}); That worked as needed. Much much simpler than what I was doing.